# Django translation don't change language

Tags: django, django-i18n

Hello i have next situation:

In settings.py:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "locale"),
)
LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('ru', 'Russian'),  
]

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
```

In urls.py i have:

```
 url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    #url(r'^jsi18n/$', javascript_catalog, js_info_dict, name='javascript-catalog'),
    url(r'^admin_tools/', include('admin_tools.urls')),
```

Language change form:

```
           <form id="lang-bar" action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
                <select name="language">
                    {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
                    {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
                    {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
                    {% for language in languages %}
                        <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                            {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
                        </option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <input class="button" type="submit" value="{% trans 'Change' %}" />
            </form>
```

I have created locale and translated and compile it, but when i click change the language isn't change. It other project where  `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'` this code work great

Answer (score 1):

Sorry my bad forgot to add `'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',` to `MIDDLEWARE` in settings.py